# Leaving out "the" article, correct or not?

Tags: articles, zero-article

I am writing a scientific article and the title reads something like:

> Dimensionality reduction algorithms : tackling complex organization of datasets

I had a <s>doubt</s> **question**, should I say "tackling the" or is it grammatically correct to leave it out?

Comment: I haven't come across a recommendation to leave a gap before a colon in running script. // 'Grammaticality' only really fully applies to sentence structure. Adding a 'the' here is probably incongruous (almost a little unprofessional). But I'd be tempted to add one on odd days during the month, as I feel the cadence is then superior. Neither is wrong. Grammaticality isn't the issue: style is.

Comment: thanks for the humorous answer :)

Comment: Article titles are not usually full sentences, so the rules of sentence grammar don't necessarily apply, and articles are often omitted.

Comment: Quite aside from the presence of absence of "the", I think the subtitle is very confusingly worded, to the point that even though I already know what dimensionality reduction is, I don't quite understand what the subtitle is trying to say.

Comment: Omitting articles is very common in article titles. See The Onion for inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

*The* is not required because the question "which complex organization of datasets?" doesn't matter - the "dimensionality reduction algorithms" you're associating with "complex organization of datasets" isn't dependent upon
a specific X.

Answer (score 0):

'the' is not required because no emphasis is intended here;also, no need of a space before colon.